# Why separate ETag argument for TableClient.UpdateEntity?

Tags: .net, api, azure-table-storage

Why does [TableClient.UpdateEntity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient.updateentity) have a dedicated ETag argument when it's already part of the entity argument (T:[ITableEntity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.itableentity.etag?view=azure-dotnet#azure-data-tables-itableentity-etag))?

Answer (score 1):

This is for enforcing [optimistic concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/update-entity2#remarks) during update operation.

You can either specify `*` and the entity will be updated unconditionally however when you specify any other value, then the entity will only be updated if the value specified matches the Etag of the entity on the server.

Comment: I understand that it's for optimistic concurrency, but wonder why can't it use ITableEntity.ETag instead for this check and then have a bool method argument for ignoring concurrency (even a bool argument is not necessary because ITableEntity.ETag is settable)? Also does UpdateEntity  ignore entity.ETag?

Comment: `but wonder why can't it use ITableEntity.ETag instead for this check and then have a bool method argument for ignoring concurrency?` - You may want to ask this question on the Github repo for the SDK. Developers of the SDK are the best folks to answer the question regarding their decision. `Also does UpdateEntity ignore entity.ETag?` - Yes. ETag is not updatable from the client side.